# Trying to solve this series

Tags: sequences-and-series

The following series is handed to me :

[The question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVRiN.jpg)

To be honest I worked my ass off and tore a lot of papers,But the best Result I have reached so far is this :(

[My best effort!!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVNoa.jpg)

Please tell me the final answer or at least  give me a clue that where should I go from this

Thanks in advance

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: What exactly do you want to ask? You cannot *solve* a series.

Comment: it is a sum of geometric series: $q_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^kc=c(1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^{n-1})=c\cdot \frac{1-x^n}{1-x}$.

Comment: I wanna get rid of the series..

Comment: Multiply $q_n$ by x then find $$q_n-x.q_n$$ you will find the answer by your self. $$q_n=c(1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^{n-1})\\xq_n=c(x+x^2+\cdots+x^{n-1}+x^{n})$$

Comment: Thank You farruhota, It's weird how my brain works. I can solve complicated problems but when someone gives me a high school problem I embarrass myself.

Comment: Merci dear Khosro, Masalan lisans daram :)))